# Issue related to timescaledb backup: "ERROR: function timescaledb_pre_restore() does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore, timescaledb

Scenario:

- PostgreSQL 11.4
- TimescaleDB 1.2.2

When trying to dump and restore a database, and following [this documentation](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/backup), I'm getting the following error message:

```
function timescaledb_pre_restore() does not exist
```

It seems to be something obvious, but I don't get it. ¿Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the post itself, you should add the exact commands you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This function didn’t exist in 1.2.2. Check out the backup/restore docs for this version here: https://docs.timescale.com/v1.2/using-timescaledb/backup

Answer (score 0):

You are using a fairly old version of TimescaleDB, and the instructions were different for 1.2.  But our docs are versioned (see the version switcher in the top of the left-hand nav).  So navigate over to version 1.2, and there are slightly different instructions:

https://docs.timescale.com/v1.2/using-timescaledb/backup